# Using both has routing and normal slash routing in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a requirement where some components needs to be shown in hash(#) routing way and some in forward slash routing way, my question is this possible if yes, any help how to implement that would be appreciated
ex:-

```
export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about/aboutView">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard#dashMenu">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about/aboutView">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard#dashMenu">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Very unclear question. What do you mean with some need to be shown in 'has routing way' and others need ' has routing way'? You wrote the same thing for both

Comment: It's rather unclear what your question is, or what any issue is you are referring to. Can you clarify your post and provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What are you tring to do?

Comment: @yanirmidler i just need two different routes to be shown on the browser one which is forward slash and one which is hash

Comment: Route paths don't use hashes. Are you *really* trying to use regular links and also hashlinks?

Comment: @DrewReese i know my code is wrong, i want help to understand how to achieve hashlinks and normal links together

Comment: Try to remove the #dashMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears you are using `react-router-dom@5` you can use the `react-router-hash-link` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to use `HashLink` links when you want. The *hash* is part of the link path target, not the path pattern used for matching by the `Switch`/`Router`.

1. Install `react-router-hash-link`: `npm install --save react-router-hash-link`.
2. Import `HashLink` from `react-router-hash-link` and replace the links that need it.
3. Remove the hash portion from the route's `path` prop.

Example:

```
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about/aboutView">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <HashLink to="/dashboard#dashMenu">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about/aboutView" component={About} />
          <Route path="/dashboard component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```